# Continuity of a function in the closed interval $[0,2]$.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity

Let, $g$ be a function defined on the interval $[0,2]$ and $x\le g(x) \le (x^{2}-x+1)$ for $0\le x \le 2$. Then,

(1) $g$ must necessarily be a polynomial.

(2) $g$ must be continuous at $x=1$.

(3) $g$ must be continuous at $x=0$ & $x=2$.

(4) $g$ must be a continuous function.

I only find that, $lim_{x\to 1} g(x)=1$ by Sandwich theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have shown, $\lim_{x\to 1}g(x)=1=g(1)$, so $g(x)$ is continuous at $x=1$. And also note $h(x)=x^2-x+1>x ,x\neq 1$, so we can set $g(x)=x, x\in (0,2)$ and $g(0)=1=h(0),g(2)=3=h(2)$, so $g$ is not continuous at $x=0,2$, hence it can't be a polynomial, since polynomial is continuous.

Comment: $\lim_{x\to 1}g(x)=1$ but how it is equal to $g(1)$?

Comment: @Panja.S. at $x=1, h(1)=1$, so $g(1)=1$ by assumption.